# Why does border-radius not work in a specific website with Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

We develop browser extensions for Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer. Our extensions insert HTML elements to websites, such as mail.google.com and email14.secureserver.net.

Our HTML element has a `border-radius` CSS attribute of 5px. In all the websites it's fine, such as mail.google.com and also in all the browsers, but in https://email14.secureserver.net/webmail.php?login=1 with Internet Explorer there is no `border-radius`, and I see these properties in red:

**In mail.google.com:**

[image]

**In email14.secureserver.net:**

[image]

What is the problem and did this website disable `border-radius`?

Is there a way to define `border-radius` which will also work on this website? I saw that `border-radius` is supported in Internet Explorer 9 and above.

How can I detect if `email14.secureserver.net` is using an old mode of Internet Explorer? And is it possible to define `border-radius` without disabling this mode?

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 but this extension should work on all versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) says it's fine to work with ie9<=. Could you post the markup? As currently I don't know how we're meant to help you without it? 
It could be *possible* that the website you're using has a class/id that is identical to your class, and hence it could be getting overridden?

Comment: What is "borderRadius" opposed to "border-radius:"? 

Perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: Check the document mode displayed by the F12 tools; if it's not IE9 standards mode or edge mode, that's probably why you're seeing the problem on that particular site.  The fix is to change the doctype for the site to a standards-based doctype, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: jQuery added `borderRadius` because it's not recognized, we defined `border-radius` with jQuery's CSS method. I added the `border-top-left-radius` manually with inspect element.

Comment: @LanceLeonard How can I detect if `email14.secureserver.net` is using an old mode of Internet Explorer? And is it possible to define `border-radius` without disabling this mode?

Comment: @Uri, the easiest way to see the document mode that a website is delivering is to go to is and use the F12 tools to see the final document mode.  In this case, it is delivering edge mode, so it's not the document mode (at least not the document mode of the rendered site).  border-radius is supported for edge mode, IE9 standards mode and later.  It's possible the difference lies in the support files used by each resource.  How is your extension inserted into the DOM of the target page?

Comment: @LanceLeonard Thank you. `email14.secureserver.net` is using document mode = 7, while other websites are using Edge. I think `border-radius` is not supported in mode 7, this is the reason why I can't define `border-radius` or `border-top-left-radius`.

Comment: @Uri, you're right, border-radius requires IE9 standards mode or later.  Check to see if the site has been placed onto that machine's compatibility view settings (which you can get to from the gear menu).  If it is, that would be why it's rendering in IE7 mode.  Removing it from the list may make a difference.

Comment: @LanceLeonard OK, thank you. I don't think this site in on the list, I guess it has some code that asks Explorer to use mode 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website can ask IE to use an older engine to render it, check the inspector, it should say if it's using some older version, wacky compatibility modes, stuff like that.

Comment: Slight correction, IE can render with a legacy *document mode* (not engine).

Comment: How can I detect if `email14.secureserver.net` is using an old mode of Internet Explorer? And is it possible to define `border-radius` without disabling this mode?

Answer (score -2):

Just based off your second screen shot, you have "`borderRadius: 5px`" before calling your "`border-top-left-radius:5px;`"

borderRadius is not correct syntax, it may be canceling out the code after it.
border-radius is supported from ie9+, so you shouldn't be having a problem.

Comment: There's no possible way that "it may be canceling out the code after it". That doesn't happen in CSS. There are no fatal errors that stop execution of the script. If a rule is not recognized, it's simply ignored.

Comment: He may well just be wondering why his "borderRadius" is not working, and the fact that it's not the correct syntax is most likely why.

Comment: jQuery added `borderRadius` because it's not recognized, we defined `border-radius` with jQuery's CSS method. I added the `border-top-left-radius` manually with inspect element.